# Recursively Copy Dotfiles from Git Repo to New System's Home Directory

Tags: recursion, bash, linux, shell, unix

I manage my `dotfiles` in a github repo.  The idea would be that I could clone the repo if I ever have to develop on a new system and symlink them to the home directory.  I could do this piecemeal manually but I wanted to write a script that automates it.

The script calls a recursive function that symlinks to my dotfiles such that:

- If a file or symlink already exists on the system, don't overwrite it.
- If  a directory exists on the system but is empty, delete the existing directory and then symlink to it
- If a file does not exist in the system, create a symlink to my `dotfiles`
- If a directory exists on the system but is NOT empty, call the recursive function on that file to my dotfiles.  So if, for eample, there is a mismatch in the contents of my `.config` directory and the system `.config` folder the recursive function is called on both the `.config` folders, symlinking to my files, following the rules above, and recursively copying them to subdirectories.

It also outputs a text log of what's going on with indentation for the level of recursion.

My questions are:
Is what I'm doing a good approach? Maybe there is a one liner that replicates my script (perhaps using `find` which I'm still learning about; I'm still learning `bash`).

Is there an obvious problem with my code? I've tested it on a system, and worked out some bugs but I just wonder if anyone more experienced can see obvious problems.

```bsh
#/bin/bash

echo_indent() # an echo function whose argument is a certain number of tabs to indent by
{
    i=0
    while [ $i -lt $1 ]
    do
        echo -n "  "
        i=$((i+1))
    done
    echo "$2"
}

recursive_link() # takes three arguments; source file, target file, and number of indents for logging output
{
    n_indents=$3 # the third argument is how muhch to indent for each level of reccursion

    # these two conditions test if one is a file and the other is a directory or vice-versa
    echo_indent $3 ====================================================
    echo_indent $3 "trying to link $1 and $2"

    if [ -f "$2" ]
    then
        echo_indent $3 "$2 already exists (file)"
        return 1
    fi

    if [ -L "$2" ]
    then
        echo_indent $3 "$2 already exists (symlink)"
        return 1
    fi

    if [ -f "$1" ] && [ -d "$2" ]
    then
        echo_indent $3 "mismatch between $1 (file) and $2 (directory)"
        return 1
    fi

    if [ -d "$1" ] && [ -f "$2" ]
    then
        echo_indent $3 "mismatch between $1 (directory) and $2 (file)"
        return 1
    fi




# Case where they are both directories
if [ -d "$1" ] && [ -d "$2" ]
then
    # if the existing system directory is empty
    if [ $(ls -A "$2" | wc -l) -eq 0 ] 
    then
        echo_indent $3 "linking directory to empty system directory"
        rm -r $2 # deleting empty directory so that `ln` works right; could use `n` option but the man page cautions against `n` in scripts
        ln -sv $1 $2 
        return 0
    fi

    echo_indent $3 "both directories, system nonempty: recursively symlinking contents"

    for fle in "$1"/.* "$1"/* #looping over dotfiles and other files
    do
        echo_indent $3 '------------------------------------------'
        echo_indent $3 "file is $fle"
        fle_used="$(basename -- $fle)" # just want the ending filename, not enclosing directories
        echo_indent $3 "basename is $fle_used"
        if [ "$fle_used" != '..' ] && [ "$fle_used" != '.' ] && [ "$fle_used" != 'symlink_recursive.sh' ] && [ "$fle_used" != "dotfiles" ] && [ "$fle_used" != "README.md" ] && [ "$fle_used" != "dotfiles/" ] && [ "$fle_used" != ".git" ] #list of files that we don't want ot copy
        then
            echo_indent $3 "applying recursion"
            #adding and subtracting indent because of bash scope rules
            n_indents=$((n_indents+1))
            recursive_link "$1/$fle_used" "$2/$fle_used" $((n_indents))
            n_indents=$((n_indents-1))
        else
            echo_indent $3 "file rejected for recursion"
        fi
    done

    return 0 # done recursing over subdirectories
    fi

    echo "linking $1 and $2"
    ln -sv $1 $2 #the file does not exist on the system, symlinking to my dotfiles
}

#actually calling the function on my cloned dotfiles and the homedirectory
recursive_link ~/dotfiles ~ 0 #third arguments is
```

Answer (score 2):

Not a complete code review but there are a few things that I would maybe change:

- Indent by n spaces instead of tabs and use `printf` instead of a slow bash loop:

  ```bsh
  echo_indent() {
     printf "%$1s%s\n" "" "$2"
  }
  ```
- Or a global variable that you would augment or shrink by one tab when entering or leaving a recursion level:

  ```bsh
  declare indent=
  echo_indent() {
     printf "%s%s\n" "$indent" "$1"
  }
  ...
  indent="    $indent"
  ...
  indent="${indent:1}"
  ```
- Test empty directories with `find` instead of `ls` which is not really for scripting:

  ```bsh
  if [ -z "$(find "$2" -type f -print -quit)" ]; then
    ...
  fi
  ```
- Use shell options to simplify some constructs:

  ```bsh
  shopt -s nullglob dotglob
  ...
  for fle in "$1"/*; do
  ...
  ```

  (note that without the `nullglob` shell option your `for fle in "$1"/.* "$1"/*` could lead to unexpected results if there are no dotfiles or no non-dotfiles.)
- Use a bash associative array to store the set of files to ignore and test if a name is in the set:

  ```
  declare -A ignore=(
    [".."]=1
    ["."]=1
    ["symlink_recursive.sh"]=1
    ["dotfiles"]=1
    ["README.md"]=1
    ["dotfiles/"]=1
    [".git"]=1
  )
  ...
  if [[ -z ${ignore["$fle_used"]:-} ]]; then
  ...
  ```
- Use in-place increment for the indentation:

  ```bsh
  recursive_link "$1/$fle_used" "$2/$fle_used" $(( $3 + 1 ))
  ```

  Or, with spaces:

  ```bsh
  recursive_link "$1/$fle_used" "$2/$fle_used" $(( $3 + 4 ))
  ```

But I would probably use `find` for all this. Example with a simplified logging part and a helper bash function; the find command must be executed in the `dotfiles` directory:

```bsh
helper() {
  printf 'trying to symlink %s to %s\n' "$1" "$2"
  if [[ -f $2 ]] || [[ -L $2 ]]; then
    printf 'skip: file or symlink %s exists\n' "$2"
    return
  elif [[ -d $1 ]] && [[ -d $2 ]] &&
       [[ -z "$(find "$2" -type f -print -quit)" ]] ||
       [[ ! -e $2 ]]; then
    rm -rf "$2"
    ln -srf "$1" "$2"
    printf 'symlink\n'
  else
    printf 'skip: %s exists and is not a file, a symlink or an empty directory\n' "$2"
  fi
}

export -f helper
find . -mindepth 1 -exec bash -c 'helper "{}" "$HOME/{}"' \;
```